# How to change gridview font?

Tags: gridview, fonts, vb.net-2010

How can I change the Gridview font in an Windows Form?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `ItemStyle-Font-Names` property on each BoundField to change the font of the items in the grid, and you can use the `HeaderStyle-Font-Names` property to change the headers.

If you want to use css, read on...

You can also use a `HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridview-header"`, then you could define a css class to do the styling:

```
.gridview-header
{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    color:  #666666;
    padding-top: 3px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
```

And you could define a css class for the entire gridview, by setting the gridview's CssClass property:

```
CssClass="gridview"
```

Then, you can set the tr property (the tr is what the gridview renders for rows) and set the font there in your css file:

```
.gridview tr
{
    /* set font properties here */
}
```

When using css in a project, you usually have a css file (call it `StyleSheet.css`, for example). Then in your aspx pages (or views if you're using MVC), you can include the stylesheet like this, assuming the `StyleSheet.css` is in a folder called `Styles` in the site root folder:

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <link href="Styles/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Comment: thanks
i made css in class in vb.net
where do i write css?
in style?
explain more,please

Comment: @niloofar - See my latest edit.